# Selenium: how to run the same test in multiple tabs at the same time?

Tags: selenium

Once you have a test defined in Selenium IDE, is it possible to run it automatically in 2 or more tabs at the same time? If not, is this something that is possible with Selenium RC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in either. You can however, have multiple browsers running, using a Selenium Grid, if you either fire up a test runner more than once or if you use a test framework that allows parallel testing like TestNG, Gradle, Maven Surefire, or pNUnit.